# Why does HashMap allow only one null key?

Tags: java, map

A `HashMap` allows only one `null` key. Is it because it allows only unique keys?  Or is there another reason?

Comment: Related [HashMap null key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945309/hashmap-null-key).  Food for thought - how do you distinguish two 'different' `null`s? What does two different `null`s mean?

Comment: What's confusing about it?  A hash is a key/value pair.  You use the key to look up the value.  If you have multiple of the same key, how do you know which one to grab to get the value?  Thus, if NULL is a key, and you can use it to look up a value, how do you expect to look up a value if there are multiple NULL keys?

Comment: Are you confusing key with value perhaps? A HashMap can have multiple null values, which can have some use e.g. with containsKey() (to distinguish null values from absent keys).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why is it confusing? The javadoc for `HashMap.put` clearly states:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced**.

It clearly states what happens when you do a `put` with a key which was already in the map. The specific case of key == null behaves in the same way: you can't have two different mappings for the null key (just like you can't for any other key). It's not a special case, for the context of your question.